# Linux Shell Scripting: if/else works on bash but not zsh or sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

Here's an installer I'm writing with all the irrelevant bits removed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "In the prompt below, type 'install' or 'remove' (without the quotes)"
echo "If you type neither, this script will terminate."
read -p "Action to perform: " OPERATION

if [ "$OPERATION" == "install" ]
then
  echo "Installing..."
  echo "Install successful!"
elif [ "$OPERATION" == "remove" ]
then
  echo "Removing..."
  echo "Remove successful!"
else
  echo "Aborting with no actions"
fi
```

This script works exactly as you'd expect. When I type `install`, the install section executes, when I type `remove` the remove section executes and finally when I type random characters, it aborts.

But the same script with the `#!/bin/bash` replaced with either `#!/bin/sh` or left empty (my regular shell is ZSH), it errors out:

```
In the prompt below, type 'install' or 'remove' (without the quotes)
If you type neither, this script will terminate.
Action to perform: sdfsdfdsf
./test.sh: 7: [: sdfsdfdsf: unexpected operator
./test.sh: 11: [: sdfsdfdsf: unexpected operator
Aborting with no actions
```

For some context, I'm on Ubuntu Studio 18.04 with `zsh --version` printing `zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: On my laptop within zsh (5.3.1), read doesn't work as expected (read: -p: no coprocess). The if statement does work but only with asingle `=`, not with `==`. Maybe if you use `test` instead? (`if test "inst" != "install"; then echo "yes"; fi`). Your script should work within `sh`, however.

Comment: @wingedrhino : If you don't have a #! line and invoke the script just by name, not via `zsh NAME`, zsh too will use /bin/sh, so this is not really a zsh issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ubuntu 18.04, `/bin/sh` is symlink to `/bin/dash` whose `[ ... ]` does not support `==`. You can use `[ = ]` which also works for zsh.

```
[STEP 101] # grep 18.04 /etc/os-release
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
[STEP 102] # ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2019-02-14 09:49 /bin/sh -> dash
[STEP 103] # /bin/sh
# [ a == b ]
/bin/sh: 1: [: a: unexpected operator
# test a == b
/bin/sh: 2: test: a: unexpected operator
# [ a = b ]
# test a = b
# exit
[STEP 104] #
```

Note that [POSIX only mentions "="](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128) and according to [dash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), "*Only features designated by POSIX, plus a few Berkeley extensions, are being incorporated into this shell.*"

Comment: In other words, `==` as a conditional operator is a Bash extension, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work in other shells.  The standard string-equality comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: Aah thanks! It works now. I rarely remember my shell scripting syntax so end up googling everything. I guess a lot of websites with references automatically assume you use bash!

Answer (score 2):

Fist you should update your shebang to use `sh` instead of `bash` and then you will have to use a slightly different syntax. You can use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for detailed errors.

There are a tone of articles describing the difference like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/3872881

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "In the prompt below, type 'install' or 'remove' (without the quotes)"
echo "If you type neither, this script will terminate."
echo -n "Action to perform: "
read -r OPERATION

if [ "$OPERATION" = "install" ]
then
  echo "Installing..."
  echo "Install successful!"
elif [ "$OPERATION" = "remove" ]
then
  echo "Removing..."
  echo "Remove successful!"
else
  echo "Aborting with no actions"
fi
```

Comment: Good, but I thought the preferred way to set the interpreter is now this:

`#!/usr/bin/env sh`